# Python не работает сложение

Tags: python

```
test_results = [
    
[85.4, 71.6, 93.2, 65.8, 45.0],

    [89.5, 80.0, 95.5, 76.5, 72.0]

]

average = 0

for result in test_results:

    average += result
```

Comment: `average += sum(result)` ?

Comment: Не за что. Если не хочешь читать учебники и сообщения об ошибках, то лучше сразу бросай программирование и не трать время попусту, займись чем-нибудь более понятным тебе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что элемент `result` это элемент списка test_results. Т.е. `[85.4, 71.6, 93.2, 65.8, 45.0]` и `[89.5, 80.0, 95.5, 76.5, 72.0]`.
Получается `0 + [85.4, 71.6, 93.2, 65.8, 45.0] = ???`  не понятно что.

Нужно добавить цикл, который будет суммировать элементы вложенных списков.

```
for i in result:

    average += i
```